# Need a hint on proving a limit property.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Need just a small hint on how to prove $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x+a)$ from definition of limit.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $x-a$?

Comment: Ooops, yeah I fixed it.

Comment: Hint: If $x$ is approaching $a$, what is $x-a$ approaching...

Comment: $x + a \rightarrow a$ as $x \rightarrow 0$, so the original post was correct.

Comment: Which definition of the limit? The epsilon delta one or the graphical one?

Comment: Also, that statement is not true. Consider the case where that limit does not exist. Nonexstence is not equal. Otherwise we would have some constant defining nonexsistence. Although one could muse that two places have the same sort of nonexsistence. However, I would find such things to be nonsense. Not that I deny the possibility of such a concept. Rather, I would find it foriegn and useless in my current understanding of things.

Comment: Epsilon delta. Assuming both limits exist.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = L$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. There exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |x - a| < \delta$. Reinterpret for the alternative variable $y = x - a$.

Comment: It was actually for x+a, but can you give me another hint?

Comment: Yes, that is reflected in the new variable, as $x = y + a$. Here, we see that $|f(y + a) - L| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |y| < \delta$ which is the definition for $\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} f(y + a) = L$.

Comment: Okay, makes sense now. This method is called substitution, right? I need to get better at it.

Comment: I just had a hard time understanding how we are allowed to let x=y+a in the first limit when a is a constant. Is it because the first and second limits, from the definition, are valid for all x?

Comment: That last part doesn't quite make sense, since the limit is only concerned with arbitrarily small neighborhoods of $x = a$. I immediately glanced at the definition of the limit for $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = L$ and noticed that, in order to agree with the definition of the limit for $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x + a) = L$, it would be sufficient that $x - a$ be considered as a variable in itself because its magnitude is less than $\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x) := f(x+a)$. Then the image of $f$ in $(a-\delta, a+ \delta)$ is the same as the image of $g$ in $(-\delta,\delta)$. What does this imply?